# Why is the does a website breaks in Internet Explorer 9?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, internet-explorer-9, wordpress-theming

I am trying to find a reason for this website breaking under ie9. Main page is ok ( (www.spirulina.pl), but when I open any category page, i.e. http://www.spirulina.pl/category/dieta
header breaks.

I found out that there is an error when using chrome inspect element:

> Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://www.spirulina.pl/?shaken-custom-content=css&v=20120305125451".

Could this be a reason? If yes, how can I correct this error?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the resource from http://www.spirulina.pl/?shaken-custom-content=css&v=20120305125451 with a header of "text/css".

Comment: thanks, but how should this be done? would this be enough:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.spirulina.pl/?shaken-custom-content=css&amp;v=20120305125451" media="screen" type="text/css">

Comment: No, from your PHP script - so in your file serving the custom css, something like `header('Content-Type: text/css');`.

Comment: Still not found a way to do it, but will keep trying. Do you think this is why the theme breaks?

Comment: It might be. What do you mean by the header "breaks"?

Comment: I mean visually, the template breaks at the top of the page in ie9 (not the html header)

Comment: OK. Let me look. Internet Explorer's being slow because I've not used it for ages, haha.

Comment: Ok, there must be something else going on - I deleted the line which was causing html header error and error disapeared - nothing happened to the theme so looks like it was redundant. However, the problem I described first - breaking of a template in ie9 - still exists

Comment: Was it a `<hr>` by any chance?